# Flutter text form field validation

Tags: flutter, api, dart, validation

Hello I am creating a mobile number verification screen. In this I want to validate the Indian mobile number. But my code is not validating and I am not able to understand where the problem is. If the text form field is validated, then the api is called and if the text form field is not validated then the text form field is highlighted with alert. Please help me in resolving this issue.

```
Form(
        key: _formKeymobile,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              S.of(context).verify,
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 30.0.sp,
                  fontFamily: 'DancingScript',
                  color: Colors.purple),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            TextFormField(
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 20.0.sp),
              controller: _mobilenumber,
              validator: (value) {
                const pattern =
                    r'(^(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[\ -]\s*)?|[0]?)?[6789]\d{9}|(\d[ -]?){10}\d$)';
                final regExp = RegExp(pattern);
                if (value!.isEmpty) {
                  return S.of(context).EnterSomeText;
                } else if (value.length != 10) {
                } else if (!regExp.hasMatch(value)) {
                  return S.of(context).Mobilenumbermust10digits;
                  return S.of(context).MobileNumbermustbedigits;
                }
              },
              maxLength: 11,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: S.of(context).mobile,
                  border: OutlineInputBorder()),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 8.0,
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Checkbox(
                  checkColor: Colors.white,
                  value: isChecked,
                  onChanged: (bool? value) {
                    setState(() {
                      isChecked = value!;
                    });
                    // print(isChecked);
                  },
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.60,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(S.of(context).tcone),
                      InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            openWebsite(
                                
                                context);
                          },
                          child: Text(
                            S.of(context).tctwo,
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                          )),
                      Text("and"),
                      InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            openWebsite(
                                
                                context);
                          },
                          child: Text(
                            S.of(context).tcthree,
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                          )),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                if (isChecked == true) {
                  if (_formKeymobile.currentState!.validate() &&
                      isChecked == true) {
                    String? deviceId = await _getId();
                    if (deviceId != null) {
                      print("api called");
                    } else {
                      EasyLoading.showError("Unable to get device id");
                    }
                  }
                } else {
                  EasyLoading.showError("Please click the box");
                }
              },
              style: ButtonStyle(
                  backgroundColor:
                      MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.purple)),
              child: Text(S.of(context).otp),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 8.0,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                if (_formKeymobile.currentState!.validate() &&
                    isChecked == true) {
                  print("form validated");
                }
              },
              style: ButtonStyle(
                  backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.green)),
              child: Text("Already have OTP"),
            ),
          ],
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
validator: (value) {
                const pattern =
                    r'(^(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[\ -]\s*)?|[0]?)?[6789]\d{9}|(\d[ -]?){10}\d$)';
                final regExp = RegExp(pattern);
                if (value == null || value!.isEmpty) {
                  return S.of(context).EnterSomeText;
                } else if (value.length != 10) {
                } else if (!regExp.hasMatch(value)) {
                  return S.of(context).Mobilenumbermust10digits;
                  return S.of(context).MobileNumbermustbedigits;
                }
              },
```

and also change this:

```
onPressed: () async {
                if (_formKeymobile.currentState!.validate() &&
                      isChecked == true) {
                    String? deviceId = await _getId();
                    if (deviceId != null) {
                      print("api called");
                    } else {
                      EasyLoading.showError("Unable to get device id");
                    }
                  } else {
                  EasyLoading.showError("Please click the box");
                }
              },
```

[image]

Comment: glad to hear that, If it was useful to you please approve and up vote it so other people find it easier.